# Google OAuth with profile in scope missing name

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I have an issue with Google OAuth2 in my web application. I created client_id in the Google console and set scope to "openid email profile" in the url:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&response_type=id_token&scope=email+profile+openid&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID

After successful login Google redirects me to my URL with id_token. But when I validate this token on the backend the token is valid but in the response the "name" field is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't always return the claims you would expect. With open id connect.  Also there is no guarantee that a  user has even added a name.

If you are trying to get a users profile information you should use [People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get).  This is the best and most reliable way to get user profile information.

Don't rely on the claims.

Comment: But when I get the id_token in the mobile app using response_type=code and exchange token method, the id_token validation returns the name field. User is the same, scopes are the same, just another way to get the it_token.

Comment: Again I have spoken personally with the Oath team at google serval years ago they do not guarantee the claims in the tokens.  They recommend that you use the people api to get profile information.  You may get the claim occasionally in the id_token but its not something your going to get every time and its not something that you should count on.   If you want to validate the id token then you should be using this [iss, exp and aud](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#validatinganidtoken)